# How to prove that $S^{-1} I$ is contained in Jacobson radical of $S^{-1} A$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Consider the following question asked in my quiz on algebraic geometry:

> Let $I$ be an ideal and let $S=1+I =\{ 1+x : x\in I\}$. Prove that $S$ is a multiplicatively closed subset. Prove that $S^{-1} I$ is contained in Jacobson Radical of $S^{-1} A$.

I have proved S to be multiplicatively closed but I am struggling with the other assertion: I took an element $i/{1+i} \in S^{-1} I$, I have to prove that it lies in each maximal ideal of $S^{-1} A$.Let it not lie in some maximal ideal M,which means that <i/i+1> generates $S^{-1} A$. which means that I is not a proper Ideal of A. ( But I was never given to be proper ideal of A).So, should I assume that I is a proper ideal of A?( Is it a typo in the question?)

Kindly shed some light on this?

Comment: $I$ should be a proper ideal of $A$. Almost all the time anyone says "let $I$ be an ideal of the ring $R$", they implicitly mean a *proper* ideal. I bet if you ask your instructor, they'd confirm this, and if you bug them about it they might be more likely to remember to include the clarifying language next time!

Comment: I'm going to chip in my two cents and say that yes, it should have been phrased "proper ideal" but also add that I disagree with the previous comment: I don't think most people implicitly mean "proper ideal" when they say "ideal."  It's a good idea to have your antennae up for things like this, though!

Comment: @rschwieb I have a question in answer of hm2020 but I can't ask him as he has been banned for 1 year. Do , you mind  answering that question? I have commented it below his answer.

Comment: @No-One because it is the product of the units $1+u_1$ and $\frac{1}{1+w}$ . It is also explained at this duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4335469/29335

Comment: @rschwieb I don't think my  question is not duplicate, How are you sure that $1+u_1$ and $\frac{1} {1+w}$ are  units? Kindly elaborate!

Comment: @No-One seems you need to reread your definitions again.

Answer (score 1):

**question:** "I have proved S to be multiplicatively closed but I am struggling with the other assertion."

**Answer:** There is a criterion: If $B$ is a commutative ring with Jacobson radical $J(B)$, an element $x\in B$ is in $J(B)$ iff $1-xy\in B^*$ is a unit for all $y\in B$.

Let $S:=1+I$ for an ideal $I \subseteq A$ and let $B:=S^{-1}A, J:=S^{-1}(I) \subseteq B$. let

$$z_1:=\frac{x}{1+y} \in S^{-1}(I) \subseteq B$$

be any element in $J$. For any element $z_2:=u/1+v \in B$  we get

$$1-z_1z_2=\frac{1+w-ux}{1+w}=\frac{1+u_1}{1+w} \in B^*$$

for some $u_1,w\in I$. Hence for any $z_2$ it follows $1-z_1z_2$ is a unit, hence $z_1\in J(B)$.

Comment: How are you sure that $\frac{1+u_1} {1+w}$ belongs to B*?