# Saturation and Jacobson radical

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization

This question was asked in my assignment on algebraic geometry and I need help in it.

> Let A be a commutative ring. A multiplicatively closed subset S in A is called saturated if for all  $a,b \in A$, $ab\in S$ implies  that $a\in S$ and $b\in S$. Define $\bar{S} =${$ a\in A| \exists b\in A$ with $ab \in S$} to be saturation of S.

(a) Let A' be an ideal in A and let $S_{A'}=1+ A' = ${$1+a' | a\in A'$}. Then prove that S is multiplicatevely closed set in A.

I have done it.

(b)  What is the saturation $\bar{S}_{A'}$ of the multiplicatively  closed set $S_{A'}$?

Work: I think $S_{A'} = ${$a' \in A' | \exists b \in A' $ such that $a'b\in S_{A'} $}.

So,   Saturated set is all $a'\in S_{A'}$ such that $ \exists b\in S_{A'}$ such that    a'b =1+a'' $a'' \in S_{A'}$  . I don't think any further simplification is possible.

Am I right?

(c)Prove that  $A'S_{A'}^{-1} A\subseteq M_{S_{A'}^{-1} A}$= Jacobson radical of $S_{A'}^{-1} A$.

I have to show that $A'S_{A'}^{-1} A $ is contained in every maximal ideal of $S_{A'}^{-1} A$.

Let there exists a maximal ideal M which doesn't contains $A'S_{A'}^{-1} A $. What would be the contradiction?

Kindly help.

Thanks!

Comment: Hm. The Jacobson radical is the set of all $x$ where $1+xy$ is invertible for all $y$, which has to be relevant. Also, saturation of multiplicatively closed sets doesn't change the localization (by an elementary argument).

Answer (score 3):

Both of these are garbled:

> I think $S_{A'} = ${$a' \in A' | \exists b \in A' $ such that $a'b\in S_{A'} $}.

> So,   Saturated set is all $a'\in S_{A'}$ such that $ \exists b\in S_{A'}$ such that    $a'b =1+a''$[, where] $a'' \in S_{A'}$  .

You miswrote your definition two times in a row.  It should read

> I think $\bar S_{A'} = \{a \in A | \exists b \in A \text{ such that }ab\in S_{A'} \}$.

and

> So,   Saturated set is all $a\in A$ such that $ \exists b\in A$ such that    $ab =1+a'$[, where] $a' \in A'$  .

Given that latter one, you have $ab-1\in A'$, and  I don't see any other better explanation than

> $\bar S_{A'}$ is the set of all $a\in A$ such that $a+A'$ is a unit in $A/A'$.

It's funny this should happen but I'm now remembering an anecdote by Arhangelskii where he recounted a mathematician with the unfortunate habit of using $A$'s for everything: $a$, $A$, $\alpha$, $\mathfrak A$, $\mathscr A$ with various diacritics or subscripts.

Next time, use $R$ and $I\lhd R$ please instead of $A'\lhd A$.

For $c$, it suffices ot use the characterization of the Jacobson radical as the set of all elements $x$ such that $xr-1$ is a unit for every $r$ in the ring.

To that end, look at something of that form: $\frac{i}{j+1}\frac{r}{k+1}-1$ where $i, j, k\in I$ and $r\in R$.

If you write $\frac{i}{j+1}\frac{r}{k+1}=\frac{ir}{m+1}$ with $m\in I$, then
$\frac{ir}{m+1}-1=\frac{ir-m-1}{m+1}$ is a unit iff $ir-m-1$ is a unit.

You should be able to take it from there...

Comment: Thanks I have understood (b) but I am unable to understand why exactly should I have a look at elements of the form: $\frac{i r }{(j+ 1) (k+1)} -1$ and how $\frac{ir-m-1} {m+1}$ is a unit iff ir-m-1 is a unit? Kindly elaborate.

Comment: @James `why exactly should I have a look at the elements of the form ...` Because **it suffices to use the characterization of the Jacobson radical as the set of all elements  such that −1 is a unit for every  in the ring.** and that is what I'm checking.

Comment: `how ... is a unit iff $ir-m-1$ is a unit?` Remember $\frac{1}{m+1}$ is a unit, and since the product of two units is a unit, you can deduce that $ux$ is a unit iff $x$ is a unit.

Comment: why is 1/(m+1) is a unit?

Comment: @James everything in $S$ is a unit in $S^{-1}A$ by construction. That’s the whole reason we can even write “1/s”.

Comment: I understand your comments and what you wrote for (c) part but still I am not sure on how to compelte the proof. Can you please elaborate your answer for (c)?